# How to generate multiple .wav files with different names by using matlab loop

Tags: matlab, wav

How to generate multiple .wav files with different names by using a loop in MATLAB. Say that for example in the path folder have 10 .wav files.

```
files=dir('D:\...\...\*.wav');
z=[];
[d1,sr] = wavread('helo.wav');
for k=1:length(files);
   file_name=files(k).name;
   path=['D:\...\...\',file_name];
   fprintf('processing %s\n',path);
   [d2,sr]= wavread(path);
   a=d1+d2;
end
```

Meaning all the .wav files in `path` folder will sum with by 'helo.wav' and save the output in 10 different, .wav files?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: The title says matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have to assume a number of things since you didn't tell us them, but the following lines will save each `a` to a file named by the loop index:

```
outfile = strcat('D:\...\...\',num2str(k),'.wav');
audiowrite(outfile,a,sr)
```